# I'm a newb in Python and data-mining. Have issues regarding tokenizer & data type issues

Tags: python, csv, nltk, tokenize, text-mining

Hi~ I am having a problem while I am trying to tokenize facebook comments which are in CSV format. I have my CSV data ready, and I completed reading the file.

I am using Anaconda3; Python 3.5. (My CSV data has about 20k in rows and 1 in cols)

The codes are,

```
import csv
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize as sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
with open('facebook_comments_samsung.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader)  #list(reader)
print (your_list)
```

What comes, as a result, is something like this:

---

```
[['comment_message'], ['b"Yet again been told a pack of lies by Samsung Customer services who have lost my daughters phone and couldn\'t care less. ANYONE WHO PURCHASES ANYTHING FROM THIS COMPANY NEEDS THEIR HEAD TESTED"'], ["b'You cannot really blame an entire brand worldwide for a problem caused by a branch. It is a problem yes, but address your local problem branch'"], ["b'Haha!! Sorry if they lost your daughters phone but I will always buy Samsung products no matter what.'"], ["b'Salim Gaji BEST REPLIE EVER \\xf0\\x9f\\x98\\x8e'"], ["b'<3 Bewafa zarge <3 \\r\\n\\n  \\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x93\\r\\n\\xf0\\x9f\\x8e\\xad\\xf0\\x9f\\x91\\x89 AQIB-BOT.ML \\xf0\\x9f\\x91\\x88\\xf0\\x9f\\x8e\\xadMANUAL\\xe2\\x99\\xaaKing.Bot\\xe2\\x84\\xa2 \\r\\n\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x94\\xe2\\x80\\x93\\xe2\\x80\\x94'"], ["b'\\xf0\\x9f\\x8c\\x90 LATIF.ML \\xf0\\x9f\\x8c\\x90'"], ['b"I\'m just waiting here patiently for you guys to say that you\'ll be releasing the s8 and s8+ a week early, for those who pre-ordered.  Wishful thinking \\xf0\\x9f\\x98\\x86.  Can\'t wait!"'], ['b"That\'s some good positive thinking there sir."'], ["b'(y) #NextIsNow #DoWhatYouCant'"], ["b'looking good'"], ['b"I\'ve always thought that when I first set eyes on my first born that I\'d like it to be on the screen of a cameraphone at arms length rather than eye-to-eye while holding my child. Thank you Samsung for improving our species."'], ["b'cool story'"], ["b'I believe so!'"], ["b'superb'"], ["b'Nice'"], ["b'thanks for the share'"], ["b'awesome'"], ["b'How can I talk to Samsung'"], ["b'Wow'"], ["b'#DoWhatYouCant siempre grandes innovadores Samsung Mobile'"], ["b'I had a problem with my s7 edge when I first got it all fixed now. However when I went to the Samsung shop they were useless and rude they refused to help and said there is nothing they could do no wonder the shop was dead quiet'"], ["b'Zeeshan Khan Masti Khel'"], ["b'I dnt had any problem wd my phn'"], ["b'I have maybe just had a bad phone to start with until it got fixed eventually. I had to go to carphone warehouse they were very helpful'"], ["b'awesome'"], ["b'Ch Shuja Uddin'"], ["b'akhheeerrr'"], ["b'superb'"], ["b'nice story'"], ["b'thanks for the share'"], ["b'superb'"], ["b'thanks for the share'"], ['b"On February 18th 2017 I sent my phone away to with a screen issue. The lower part of the screen was flickering bright white. The phone had zero physical damage to the screen\\n\\nI receive an email from Samsung Quotations with a picture of my SIM tray. Upon phoning I was told my SIM tray was stuck inside the phone and was handed a \\xc2\\xa392.14 repair bill. There is no way that my SIM tray was stuck in the phone as I removed my SIM and memory card before sending the phone away.\\n\\nAfter numerous calls I finally gave in and agreed to pay the \\xc2\\xa392.14 on the understanding that my screen repair would also be covered in this cost. This was confirmed to me by the person on the phone.\\n\\nOn
```

- Sorry for your inconvenience in reading the result. My bad.

---

To continue, I added,

```
 tokens = [word_tokenize(i) for i in your_list]
 for i in tokens:
 print (i)

 print (tokens)
```

---

This is the part where I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in _slices_from_text(self, text) in line 1278 TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

---

What I want to do next is,

```
import nltk
en = nltk.Text(tokens)

print(len(en.tokens))
print(len(set(en.tokens)))
en.vocab()
en.plot(50)
en.count('galaxy s8')
```

And finally, I want to draw a wordcloud based on the data.

Being aware of the fact that every seconds of your time is precious, I am terribly sorry to ask for your help. I have been working this for a couple of days, and cannot find the right solution for my problem. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Python development. Please avoid naming your questions like this. The title is too long and contains some unimportant information. Anyway I won't downvote your question for now. I hope that you get an answer soon.

Comment: @fameman Thx. I am trying to adapt to Stack. Will do my best and thx for your advice.

Comment: Sorry to note that I made a mistake explaining the original data. The data consists of 20k in cols and 1 in row thx.

Comment: From your code it seems that the csv contains just one column, lots of rows. Be aware that you can **edit** your code, to fix the title and the poor formatting. For your own benefit, please do.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because your CSV file is turned into a list of lists-- one for each row in the file. The file only contains one column, so each of these lists has one element: The string containing the message you want to tokenize. To get past the error, unpack the sublists by using this line instead:

```
tokens = [word_tokenize(row[0]) for row in your_list]
```

After that, you'll need to learn some more python and learn how to examine your program and your variables.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I gratefully passed the error. However, I am still having trouble saying that "unhashable type : list".

My code is as follows:

type(tokens)   # list ///

en = nltk.Text(tokens) ///
print(len(en.tokens))  # 19904 ///

en.plot(50)  #  ERROR

Comment: @Alex, `tokens` is now a list of word lists. `nltk.Text` expects a flat sequence of tokens. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/699305) is how to flatten your list of lists. PS. Please follow my advice and go through some basic Python tutorials (and then the ntlk book, which takes you step by step through how to do these things).